# text inside the chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I have a dataset named `seed_l_Last_fiscal_yr_m`

```
mycols <- c("#CD534CFF","#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF", "#868686FF", "#CD534CFF")
text="Donor Details"

ggplot(seed_b_Last_fiscal_yr_m, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=donor)) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  coord_polar(theta="y")+
  xlim(c(2, 4))+
  theme_void()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input and then an explicit example of your expected dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `annotate` function. Note that you must set the `x =` value to be within the limits set by `xlim()`.

```
ggplot(seed_b_Last_fiscal_yr_m, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=donor)) +
  geom_rect() +
  annotate("text",x = 2, y = 0, label = text, size = 5, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mycols) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") + 
  xlim(2,4) + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Sample Data:

```
seed_b_Last_fiscal_yr_m <- structure(list(donor = c("TLF", "TLF", "RF/ TDP", "RF/ TDP", 
"RF/ TDP", "RF/ TDP", "RF/UCID", "RF/UCID"), amount = c(7L, 15L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 15L, 10L, 9L), ymax = c(0.02991453, 0.09401709, 0.12820513, 
0.14957265, 0.17948718, 0.24358974, 0.28632479, 0.32478632), 
    ymin = c(0, 0.02991453, 0.09401709, 0.12820513, 0.14957265, 
    0.17948718, 0.24358974, 0.28632479)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: thanks alot............but how to use this line sum(seed_l_Last_fiscal_yr_m[seed_l_Last_fiscal_yr_m$type=="Actual",]$amount) and i get 76 inside the chart how to update this value

Comment: The data you present in the question does not appear to have a column `type`. There should be no reason that you cannot use `sum` to calculate the value for `label = ` in `annotate`. For example `annotate("text",x = 2, y = 0, label = paste0(text,"\n",sum(seed_b_Last_fiscal_yr_m$amount)), size = 5, color = "black")`.

Comment: i have type value in another dataframe so how to use inside this plot @

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this without an example of the data. If you have a different question, I would recommend posting it with the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: i update the second dataframe but u just plzz edit that so that it will be more readable